# Is ${C}[0,1],\Bbb{R}$ homeomorphic to any $\Bbb{R^n}$, for an integer $n$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, banach-spaces

The norm in ${C}[0,1],\Bbb{R}$ is the norm of $L^1$

Comment: You mean homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes, I edited it

Comment: What is $C[0,1],\mathbb R$? Do you mean continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Hint: First show that $C([0,1], {\mathbb R})$ is an infinite dimensional vector space. Then show that any infinite-dimensional vector space equipped with any norm is not locally compact. Lastly, prove that $R^n$ is locally compact.

Comment: You’re right. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Is the space still path-connected after removing one element?

Answer (score 3):

No.  There are embeddings of $\mathbb R^k$ into $C([0,1], \mathbb R)$ with $L^1$ norm for all positive integers $k$: all you need is to take $k$ linearly independent continuous functions $f_j$ on $[0,1]$, and map $(t_1, \ldots, t_k) \mapsto t_1 f_1 + \ldots t_k f_k$.  But there is no embedding  of $\mathbb R^k$ into $\mathbb R^{n}$ for $k > n$.